# PHPMyAdmin Fresh Install Error 500 Nginx

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, php, phpmyadmin

I've just done a fresh install of phpmyadmin on nginx and ubuntu 22.04, however navigating to the index page is returning HTTP 500.

My error.log:

```
2023/06/24 22:52:55 [error] 1448200#1448200: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require_once(Symfony/Component/ExpressionLanguage/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/php/PhpMyAdmin/MoTranslator/autoload.php on line 2PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Symfony/Component/ExpressionLanguage/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /usr/share/php/PhpMyAdmin/MoTranslator/autoload.php on line 2" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.13, server: _, request: "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "192.168.1.19"
```

I've been trying to install phpmyadmin on this new server for a month now, tried countless things and watched so many tutorials yet to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The error is unrelated to NGINX but related to your install of phpmyadmin—it’s incomplete. It looks like you’ve installed it by a Ubuntu package. Follow the instructions at their Git repo https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin. If you clone the repo, you also need to install dependencies as well, using PHP dependency manager Composer (which is what your error is about, it's trying to load uninstalled dependencies).